# Time Machine backup solution for MacBookPro 5,3 (4TB+)

Tags: backup, time-machine, time

I have a MacBook Pro I'd like to backup using Time Machine. I have money to purchase any storage solution that will allow me to keep 4TB+ of "history" of a FileVault volume. My current solution gives me 2 TB which is not enough in terms of being able to "travel back in time" far enough. What to buy?

Incidentally:

- Does Time Machine support NAS? (USB 2.0 seems like a bottleneck, my NIC is 1Gb)
- A FireWire 800 external disk > 2 TB?
- An external RAID?

4TB+ is really a requirement and backing up to tape is not viable as I need a fast restore.

Can Time Machine "aggregate" external drives to allow for "longer time travel"? I have another computer I could use to run software RAID on it (USB though, not FC/SAS/SCSI/FW) but to me this would be too risky... would it not?

How about migrating older Time Machine backups to slower/cheaper/larger/more power efficient drives? Would the interface stay the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/products/index.php)? Data Robotics, who make Drobo devices, are certified by Apple, and their website states that both their [direct-connected (Firewire) devices](http://drobo.com/products_time_machine.aspx) and [their networked devices](http://www.drobo.com/news/pr/press_release_2010_05_20a.php) work with Time Machine.

I assume you're aware of how Time Machine works with FileVaults, as well? Essentially it'll backup the whole home-folder as a single file, hence you'll use up space on your Time Machine drive a lot faster. It can also only backup your home folder when you're logged out, as you probably know.

It's not exactly cheap, but you say you have money to spend.

Comment: Not true. Starting with 10.5 home directories are sparse-bundles, comprised of 8MB "stripes". Only the changed ones are backed up.